# Problem with Piecewise in a PDE Boundary Condition

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, boundary-conditions

I am attempting to set up a Neumann boundary condition for a PDE that evaluates differently for different times.  I am using Piecewise to do this. Here is the Boundary condition:

$$U^{3/2}[x=L,t] = -\frac{c_2}{c_1}\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}[x=L,t]
$$

In this problem, the initial condition is defined to be:

$$U[x,t=0] = z\:(a\:constant)
$$

One can see that at t=0, there is an inconsistency at x = L.  I have been seeking a work around for this, First by introducing the BC as piecewise defined, such that at t = 0, the derivative of the surface at the edge is 0, and at t > 0 it is as seen above.  Here is the code I have been using for the definition of the boundary condition:

```
BC = -C2/C1 (D[u[x, t], x] /. x -> L) == 
    Piecewise[{ {1, t = 0}, {((u[x, t])^(3/2) /. x -> L), t > 0 } } ]
```

This is the output:
$$-1. u^{(1,0)}(1,t)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\begin{array}{cc}
 u(1,t)^{3/2} & t>0 \\
 1 & t\leq 0 \\
 0 & True \\
\end{array}
 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Beyond that I don't understand the third line "0    True", this is not working to generate a consitent boundary condition at x=L and t=0 for NDSolve.  Am I using [Piecewise] incorrectly, or misapplying it here?

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental boundary condition problem is this: `D[u[x, t]` is required to be zero at `x == L`, `t = 0` but to be one at `t` infinitesimal larger.  Instead, a smooth transitions is required, both on physical and mathematical grounds.  For instance,

```
C1 = 1/10; C2 = 1/10; L = 1; tfinal34 = 4;  
GovEqFD = C2 Sqrt[u[x, t]] D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + 
      C2 (1/(2 Sqrt[ u[x, t]])) (D[u[x, t], x])^2 +  
      C1 (u[x, t] - 1) D[u[x, t], x] - D[u[x, t], t] == 0 ;
BC34 = {u[0, t] == 1, -C2/C1 (D[u[x, t], x] /. x -> L) == (1 - Exp[-10 t]) u[L, t]^(3/2)};
IC34 = u[x, 0] == 1;
FDsol4 = NDSolve[{GovEqFD, BC34, IC34}, u[x, t], {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tfinal34}] // First;
Plot3D[u[x, t] /. FDsol4, {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, tfinal34}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

produces the desired solution.

**Addendum: Steady State Solution**

It may be of interest to compute the steady state solution, obtained simply by deleting time dependence from the PDE.

```
s = NDSolve[{C2 Sqrt[v[x]] D[v[x], {x, 2}] + C2 (1/(2 Sqrt[ v[x]])) (D[v[x], x])^2 +    
    C1 (v[x] - 1) D[v[x], x] == 0, v[0] == 1, -C2/C1 (D[v[x], x] /. x -> L)== v[L]^(3/2)}, 
    v[x], {x, 0, L}, Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {v[0] == 1, v'[0] == -1/4}}] // First;
Plot[{Evaluate[u[x, t] /. FDsol4 /. t -> {1, 2, 4}], v[x] /. s}, {x, 0, L}, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, "u, v"}]
```

[image]

The red curve is the steady state solution.  The time-dependent solution converges to it at about `t == 10`.